# mininet access to services on host VM

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, systemd-networkd

Scenario / Background:

So, I am trying to simulate couple of hosts in mininet. I want to run network service (NFS - Network File System - running on port 2049) on one of the host in mininet topology, and I want to port scan(using nmap) from another host in mininet topology and identify the service as running.

Problem:

I have installed all the necessary services and did all of the configurations using this(link) article for the deployment of NFS. I have also enabled the firewall and inserted the rule. I have also cross checked that the service is running and active. The problem is that when I scan using nmap, the port is always close. I know there is a special script in nmap (i.e., nmap -sV --script=nfs-ls ) for scanning NFS service running on port, that also doesn't work.

The problem I see is that when running (netstat -a) on main VM, NFS is in listening mode but when I try to run the same command (i.e., netstat -a) in mininet host running NFS service there is nothing listening.

**Note: The ping and netcat is working between two hosts. Also, the simple, UDP and TCP nmap scans command are also not identifying port as open.

Looking forward to get some help...!! :)

Comment: Your link is not working in your question. Please go back and add it.

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-20-04